Is it possible to automate Music.app to play a random album by one specific artist?
I have lots of 'albums' in my library in Apple Music which are by a certain artist.  I find these good to work to.  They are all relatively similar (dance music mixes.)
I would like to make an automation so that I can trigger Music.app to play one of these albums at random.
Is there any way to do this?  I've been looking at the AppleScript dictionary from Music.app and I can't see any way to get every album by xxx
Thanks

Right - that wasn't as difficult as I thought it would be.
So - you have to make a smart playlist that lists all tracks whose album artist is the artist you require.
Then this script will pick a random album from that playlist.  I suspect that it will keep playing after that album is complete, but I don't mind about that.
set selectedAlbumArtistPlaylistName to "Above & Beyond" -- replace with your smart playlist name.

tell application "Music"
    set shuffle enabled to true
    set shuffle mode to albums
    play playlist named selectedAlbumArtistPlaylistName
end tell

Source: Applescript and iTunes: enable shuffle by song or album and play?
